# How do i Horizontally align my boxes?

Tags: html, css

I have created 3 boxes. With UL/LI. But it doesn't seem to horizontally line up itself.

I have tried, `float:right;` and `display: inline-block;` both of which does not align it.

[Preview Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lRPN.png)

 
This is my code

```css
#box1 {
  height: 300px;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: grey;
  display: inline-block
}

#box2 {
  height: 300px;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: grey;
  display: inline-block
}

#box3 {
  height: 300px;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: grey;
  display: inline-block
}

.boxy {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Askar Photography</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1 class="logo"><img src="Assets/logo.png"></h1>
    <input type="checkbox" id="nav-toggle" class="nav-toggle">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <label for="nav-toggle" class="nav-toggle-label">
                  <span></span>
                </label>
  </header>

  <div class="content">
    <ul class="boxy">
      <li>
        <div id="box1"></div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div id="box2"></div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div id="box3"></div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>



</body>



<!--<div id="box2"></div> -->


</html>
```

Basically, This boxes will be filled with content and must be aligned horizontally with equal spaces in between. I tried googling and following step by step guide, But to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
use below code: it will help u  


<style>
     #box1 {
        height: 300px;
        width: 250px;
        background-color: grey;
        display: inline-block;
         margin-right:10px;

    }

    #box2 {
        height: 300px;
        width: 250px;
        background-color: grey;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right:10px;
    }

    #box3 {
        height: 300px;
        width: 250px;
        background-color: grey;
        display: inline-block
    }

    .boxy{
        list-style: none;
        display: flex;
        width:100%;
    }

     </style>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to do the following:

```
.boxy {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#box1, #box2, #box3 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Check out https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ for more detail on flex and it's uses. It is quite a neat little tool to use when you need responsive, evenly spaced items on your page.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're not changing the display type of those `<li>` tags. It is them which need to be set as `display: inline-block;`.

So basically you can take the display property off from `#box1`, `#box2` and `#box3`. Instead, add the following:

```
.boxy > li { display: inline-block; }
```

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is add the following to `.boxy`:

`text-align:center;`

and change the property `display:inline-block` to `display:block` in `.boxy`

See for yourself, I have edited the above in your code, and its working perfectly.

```css
#box1 {
  height: 300px;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: grey;
  display: inline-block
}

#box2 {
  height: 300px;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: grey;
  display: inline-block
}

#box3 {
  height: 300px;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: grey;
  display: inline-block
}

.boxy {
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Askar Photography</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1 class="logo"><img src="Assets/logo.png"></h1>
    <input type="checkbox" id="nav-toggle" class="nav-toggle">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <label for="nav-toggle" class="nav-toggle-label">
                  <span></span>
                </label>
  </header>

  <div class="content">
    <ul class="boxy">
      <li>
        <div id="box1"></div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div id="box2"></div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div id="box3"></div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>



</body>



<!--<div id="box2"></div> -->


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your li tags display as inline-blocks, this is because browsers default all li's to block type element.

```
.boxy > li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: It's current stated as this. But still does not work

Comment: i removed all display: inline-block; code for all the boxes except the parent div,i.e ".boxy"